# what's wrong with string:tokens

Tags: split, erlang, token

that's part of my code

```
parse1(["$WP",String]) -> 
    io:format(String++"~n"),
    parse2(string:tokens(String, "=")).

parse2(["UNCFG"|Command]) -> 
    io:format(Command++"~n"),
    uncfg(string:tokens(Command, ",")).

uncfg([Line]) ->
    io:format("just why "++Line++"~n");

uncfg([Password|Device_ID])  -> ...
```

so, everything is simple, exept one thing - function **string:tokens**
firstly , in **parse1** function, it works properly, for example splits **"UNCFG=1,2,3"**
to **"UNCFG"** and **"1,2,3"**.

and in **parse2** function no, **no splitting**
and, i get an error
....gps_tracker,uncfg[[["1,2,3"]]]...
exept getting mine ["1","2","3"]

i've added

```
uncfg([Line]) -> ...
```

now every time i get my "just why"

and, really, why, what's the difference?

i've heard about **re:split**, and, yeap, it works in that case. cool
but i really want to know what's wrong there. I'm just studying erlang.
I think it's simple question .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I've been running those commands in the shell:

```
1> ["UNCFG"|Command] = string:tokens("UNCFG=1,2,3", "=").
["UNCFG","1,2,3"]
2> [Line] = string:tokens(Command,",").
[["1,2,3"]]
3> io:format("just why "++Line++"~n").
just why 1,2,3
```

So it does it work as one should expect.

But what is your argument to parse1/1 ?

---

By the way, that last line definitely should be

```
io:format("just why ~s~n",[Line]).
```

---

Heck, I think I know what your error is: You assume the wrong things, and a list of a list is not a string (some functions accept deep lists, but not string:tokens/2). Marcelo and Monk_code were somehow right, but not for the good reasons.

With the pattern **["UNCFG"|Command]**, Command contains the entire **tail** of your list, and is itself a list. So you get these results:

```
1> string:tokens(["1,2,3"],",").
[["1,2,3"]]
```

With the pattern **["UNCFG",Command]**, Command is the second element of your list, which seems to be what you want (or not, you're not very clear):

```
1> string:tokens("1,2,3",",").  
["1","2","3"]
```

But this last output will not match your first uncfg/1 pattern. It will match the second one, with password containing "1" and Device_ID ["2","3"], because once again because you match the tail of the list.

Learn yourself some good erlang, particularly the [pattern matching stuff](http://learnyousomeerlang.com/syntax-in-functions).

Comment: oh, great! i don't know how it was worked previously, but , really, i have Command = ["1,2,3"], except "1,2,3". Many thanks!

adding [] like

`parse2(["UNCFG"|[Command]) ->`

instead

`parse2(["UNCFG"|Command) -> `
solved problem. Cool! Thanks for attention!

Comment: FYI: `["UNCFG"|[Command]]` really is the same as `["UNCFG",Command]`